# Why doesn't the overridden equals(Object) method in the Boolean class require a boolean/Boolean as an argument

Tags: java, equals

The following coding mistake is possible because the Boolean equals(Object) method doesn't require a boolean/Boolean argument:

```
private void foo() {
    Boolean isSomeConditionTrue = false;
    String doSomething = "YES";
    if(isSomeConditionTrue.equals(doSomething)) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

This code won't "do something" because the coder forgot to evaluate doSomething as a String in the predicate.  Why does the Boolean equals accept Object instead of boolean/Boolean as an argument?

Comment: Because it's inherit from `Object.equals(Object obj)`

Comment: Chalk this up to LSP (every object must conform to Object). However not all type systems work this way. I personally think C# got it mostly correct by allowing *non polymorphic* operator overloading, so `isComeConditionTrue == doSomething` (in C#) would have resulted in a compiler error while using `Equals` (in C#) would have the same issue(s) as shown here. One nice (or forced) situation of a polymorphic equals in Object is for when used as part of a collection without requiring refinement along a "comparable" or "equatable" interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `equals()` is defined in the `Object` class.

There is no possible signature it could have that would do what you want.
(without making `Object` generic, which would defeat the purpose)

Comment: Isn't the Boolean equals() overridden to compare the actual value rather than the object itself (i.e. memory location)?

Comment: @NathanAdams: Yes, but the override cannot change the parameter type.  (since you can always pass an `Object` by calling through the base class)

Answer (score 3):

This method overrides

```
Object.equals(Object)
```

and as such must accept all objects.

Similarly you can write

```
if (isSomeConditionTrue == doSomething)
```

even though this can never be true either.

One way around this is to avoid using Wrappers which cannot be null anyway. i.e. Your code will only work if the `Boolean` is not null so don't use the wrapper, use the primitive.

```
private void foo() {
    boolean isSomeConditionTrue = false;
    String doSomething = "YES";
    if(isSomeConditionTrue == doSomething) { // doesn't compile
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Primitives are not only faster, they make it clearer that the value cannot be null and you can use the normal Java operations like `==` `!=` `>` etc.

Comment: Why in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java/?v=source) the method doesn't have the `@Override` annotation?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it can take a *while* for best practices to be introduced into the core libraries. If's not broken, don't fix it. Even in Java 8u40 this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` is a method on Object and the method contract requires that the parameter be an Object.  The contract for equals states that if the object is the wrong type then it should return false.

So you must convert `doSomething` into a Boolean first.  Note that even `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` only will return a Boolean.TRUE if the String word "true" ignoring case.  "yes" will not parse as TRUE.